# Calculate the sum of al the input field multiplied by n

Tags: jquery

This is my code to calculate the sum of values in all text fields:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.fname').keyup(function () {

    var total = 0,
        valid_labels = 0,
        average;

    $('.fname').each(function () {

        var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);

        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            valid_labels += 1;
            total += val;
        }
            
    });
    
    $('#result').text(total);
    
});
    });
```

It works perfect, but I want that each value of the input field will be multiplied by a different n (I want to put it inside the input field line, but I don't know which att I need to use).

For example:

```
 <input type="text" id="fname1" name="fname1" class="fname" **XXX**="3">
 <input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2" class="fname" **XXX**="5">
```

Then I want to use jQuery to calculate the sum. Like this:

**10 x 3 + 20 x 5 = 130**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an `each()` method inside event `keyup` by setting the nulling variable to `val`.

```
var val = 0;
```

Use the format attribute `data-`, treating as a `data()` method.

```
$(this).data("xxx")
```

A simple example: **1 x 3 + 1 x 5 + 1 x 7 = 15**

```js
$(".fname").keyup(function () {
    var val = 0;
    $(".fname").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "" && !isNaN(val)) {
            val += parseInt($(this).val() * $(this).data("xxx"));
        }
    });
    $("#result").text(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="fname1" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="3" />
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="5" />
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="7" />

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#fname1,#fname2").on('input change', function() {
  var val_1 = parseInt($("#fname1").val());
  var val_2 = parseInt($("#fname2").val());
  var multiply_1 = parseInt($("#fname1").attr('**XXX**'));
  var multiply_2 = parseInt($("#fname2").attr('**XXX**'));
  //make 0 if value is NaN
  val_1 = (isNumber(val_1)) ? (val_1) : 0;
  val_2 = (isNumber(val_2)) ? (val_2) : 0;
  let total = 0;
  total += (val_1 * multiply_1);
  total += (val_2 * multiply_2);
  let text = `${val_1} * ${multiply_1} + ${val_2} * ${multiply_2} = ${total}`;
  console.log(text);
});


function isNumber(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fname1" name="fname1" class="fname" **XXX**="3">
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname2" class="fname" **XXX**="5">
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stack Overflow. Every answer should inlude an educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr` in JQuery to get the multiplication factor.

```
var val = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
val multiply = parseInt($(this).attr('**XXX**'), 10);
if (!isNaN(val)) {
   valid_labels += 1;
   total += val * (!isNaN(multiply) ? multiply : 1);
}
```

Also make sure you use different IDs for each field. They are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

This will work without jQuery and will still get you the right result when you change your input values several times over:

```js
const inps=document.querySelectorAll("body input.fname"), res=document.getElementById("result");
inps.forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 let sum=0;
 inps.forEach(el=>sum+=el.value*el.dataset.xxx);
 res.textContent=sum;
}))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="fname1" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="3" />
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="5" />
<input type="text" id="fname2" name="fname" class="fname" data-XXX="7" /><br>
<p id="result"></p>
```

It will also respond to paste operations by mouse or other means of input, instead of only focussing on the `keyup` event.